# Вопрос по Python. Dict. Функция

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

```
from math import sin
def math_func(n, f):
    return {'квадрат': n**2, 'куб': n**3, 'корень': n**0.5, 'модуль': abs(n), 'синус': sin(n)}[f]


print(math_func(int(input()), input()))
```

Программа при вводе человека целого числа и слова, возвращает проделанную работу с этим числом.

Объясните, пожалуйста, как так произошло, что в этой программе [f] после словаря возвращает значение, почему словарь без названия возвращает значение.

Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: А почему бы и нет, собственно? Не очень понятно, что вам непонятно. Словари умеют возвращать значение для указанного ключа с помощью квадратных скобок, вот и всё. Наличие или отсутствие названия не имеет никакого значения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы не положите объект в переменную, то это не значит, что объект будет неполноценным, если на объект указывают ссылки (он еще нужен в работе программы), то этот объект, в данном случае словарь, `Python` не потеряет и позволит с ним работать в случае обращения к нему, потому что переменная - это всего лишь ссылка на область памяти, где хранится значение объекта, если переменной не будет, то эта область памяти все равно будет существовать.

При создании любого объекта ему автоматически присваивается числовое значение `id` (адрес в памяти, где располагается объект), к которому `Python` в последствии обращается.

```
print(id({'x': lambda x: x ** 2})) -> 1711995308928
```

Удалением ненужных объектов на которые нет ссылок занимается "сборщик мусора", про него подробнее советую почитать [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/417215/).